# How to remove a message from the Kafka topic using kafka-node

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-node

I have created a producer and a consumer to send and consume messages from a Kafka topic using "kafka-node" package. The producer and consumer are calling through an API. POST method is used for sending message to the topic, while a GET method is used to grab the message from the topic at the consumer.

When I calling the consumer API after a I send message to the KAFKA, all the previous messages are consoled in the `consumer.on('message', function(message){})`.

I need only the last message, which was sent from the producer.

### producer.js

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
const Admin = require('kafka-node/lib/admin');
var Producer = kafka.Producer,
client = new kafka.KafkaClient(),
producer = new Producer(client);
producer.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('Producer is ready');
});

producer.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Producer is in error state');
    console.log(err);
})

const createProducer = async(req,res,next) => {
    var sentMessage = JSON.stringify(req.body.messages);
    payloads = [
        { topic: req.body.topic, messages: sentMessage, partition: 0}
    ];
    producer.createTopics(req.body.topic, function(err,data){
        console.log("createtopic error"+err);
    })
    producer.send(payloads, function( err, data) {
        console.log(payloads);
    })
    res.send({
        message: 'Successfully send data from producer',
        payloads: payloads
    })
}

module.exports = {createProducer}
```

### consumer.js

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');

const createConsumer = async(req,res,next) =>{
    var topic = req.params.topic;
    
    Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
    client = new kafka.KafkaClient(),
    // offset = new kafka.Offset(client),
    consumer = new Consumer(client,
        [{ topic: topic, offset: 0}],
        {
            autoCommit: false,

        }
    );
    consumer.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log('message : ',message.value);
    });

    res.send({
        message: "consumer created : ",
        topic: topic
    })
    consumer.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Error:',err);
    })
    
    consumer.on('offsetOutOfRange', function (err) {
        console.log("absbs");
        topic.maxNum = 2;
        offset.fetch([topic], function (err, offsets) {
            if (err) {
              return console.error(err);
            }
            var min = Math.min.apply(null, offsets[topic.topic][topic.partition]);
            consumer.setOffset(topic.topic, topic.partition, min);
        });
    })
}

module.exports = {createConsumer}
```

### router.js

```
const express = require("express");
const kafkaConsumer = require("../kafka/consumer") // create routes for consumer
const kafkaproducer = require("../kafka/producer") // create routes for producer

router.post("/kafka/producer",kafkaproducer.createProducer);
router.get("/kafka/consumer/:topic",kafkaConsumer.createConsumer);

module.exports = router;
```

### index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var router = require('./routes/routes');
const {
    PORT
  } = require("./config/config");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use( bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('Kafka producer running at 5000');
});

app.use('/', router)

module.export = app;
```

How can I get the last message without using any array or anything.

Is there any way to delete the topic?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you have to set consumer offset `latest` which is last published message for given topic.

```
consumer = new Consumer(client,
    [{ topic: topic, offset: latest}],
    {
        autoCommit: false,

    }
```

to delete a topic here is the command

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <zk>:2181 --delete --topic <topic name>
```

Note: This will have no impact if delete.topic.enable is not set to true.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.
The `offset: latest` not worked for me.

The consumer always reading all the messages from the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in the code, Now I can retrieve the latest message from my topic.

I have created consumer inside the `offset.fetchLatestOffsets([topics],cb)`, and made some changes in the consumer options.

[Please check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70588682/17779970)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).