# How to consume the latest message from Kafka-consumer using NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-node

I have created a NodeJS application to insert data into a MongoDB collection. This database insertion is done by using a Kafka. Kafka-node is the plugin I have used to call Kafka.

I can create the topic and send a message to the consumer at the producer level. The message and topic are taken from the POST request.
[This is how I call the Kafka. Parameters are topic and message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0rRP.png)

Every time I call this API, the producer is creating a new message and sent it to the consumer. In each call, all previous messages will be returned to the consumer.

I have used the `fromOffset: 'earliest'` and `fromOffset: 'latest'` options to restrict the previous messages, not working.

Can anyone give me a suggestion?
Version of Kafka-node

```
"kafka-node": "^5.0.0",
```

Code I have used

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
var url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/';
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url);
var Producer = kafka.Producer,
    client = new kafka.KafkaClient(),
    offset = new kafka.Offset(client),
    Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
    producer = new Producer(client);
producer.on('ready', function () {
        console.log('Producer is ready');
    });
producer.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Producer is in error state');
        console.log(err);
    })
const createProducer = async(req,res,next) => {
  var topic = req.body.topic;
  var sentMessage = JSON.stringify(req.body.messages);
  producer.send(payloads, async function( err, data) {
        })
  client = new kafka.KafkaClient(),
  consumer = new Consumer(client,
            [
                { topic: topic, partition: 0 }
            ],
            {
                autoCommit: false,
                fromOffset: 'earliest'
            }
        );
   consumer.on('message', async function (message) {            

      console.log("Message : "+JSON.stringify(message))
      try {            
        var currentdate = new Date(); 
        var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
            + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
            + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
            + currentdate.getSeconds();
        var abb = await createListing(mongoClient,
            {
              topic: topic,
              message: sentMessage,
              time: datetime
             }
             );
             
      } catch (e) {
         console.error(":"+e);
      }
       finally {
                
       }
    });
     await mongoClient.close();
        res.send({
            message: 'Successfully send data from producer',
            payloads: payloads
        })

    async function createListing(client, newListing){
        await mongoClient.connect();
        const result = await 
       
      client.db("sample_airbnb").collection("listingsAndReviews").insertOne(newListing);
        console.log(`New listing created with the following id: ${result.insertedId}`);
        return result.insertedId;
      }
}
```

[The Messages consumed at the consumer are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iejYg.png)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You consumer will always consume all offsets that have not been marked consumed by its consumer group before.

This means that after consuming a given message (or a batch of messages), you need to commit the highest consumed offset to your Kafka cluster, to effectively mark those messages as consumed. Only then will your consumer group not re-consume those messages on startup.

To commit your offsets, you can either use kafka.js’s `autoCommit` feature (which you explicitly disabled in your implementation), or manually commit your offsets using the API provided by kafka.js.

You can find the documentation to both here: https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming#a-name-auto-commit-a-autocommit

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in the code, Now I can retrieve the latest message from my topic.

I have created consumer inside the `offset.fetchLatestOffsets([topics],cb)`, and made some changes in the consumer options.

```
var payloads = [
    { topic: topicName, messages: messageTotopic, partition: 0}
];
producer.send(payloads, async function(err, data) {

});
var client = new kafka.KafkaClient();
offset.fetchLatestOffsets([topic], async function (error, offsets) {
    if (error)
        console.log(error);
    offsetA = JSON.stringify(offsets[topic][0])
    console.log('offset Value:: '+offsetA);
    var consumer = new Consumer(
        client,
        [
            {
                topic: topic,
                partition: 0,
                offset: offsetA-1, // Offset value starts from 0
            }
        ], {
            autoCommit: false,
            fromOffset: true,
        }
    );
    consumer.on('message', async function (message) {
        console.log("Message from last offset:: " + JSON.stringify(message)); // will return the latest message.
        consumer.close();
    });
});
```

Using this way I am able to overcome the memory leakage issue related to the event emitters in the `KafkaClient`.